# DataSource, bind more then 1 value

Tags: c#, data-binding

I want to bind more then 1 columns to drop down list, so that I can get the column values when user clicks a button,

```
    ddlListMine.DataSource = GetSomeChickens();
    ddListMine.DataTextField = "ChickenName";
    ddListMine.DataValueField= "NumberOfEggsChickenLay";
    ddListMine.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please Please Please Select....", "0"));
    ddListMine.DataBind();
```

I have another column "ChickenType", which I want to access in Selected Index change column.

`GetSomeChickens()`; returns 6 columns, including `ChickenName`, `NumberOfEggsChickenLay`, `ChickenType` and so on...

**Edit**

Off course, I can call database again in selected index change method, but there must be a way around i think

Comment: GetSomeChickens can return collection of your "desired type" (i.e. Chicken here). On selected index change, check currently selected item and access the column you desire.

Comment: You can have the Chicken primary key as the `DataValueField`. And then call a function `GetChickenById(pkCkickenId)`

Comment: @Magnus That's the point, I don't want to call database again, unless I didn't understood you

Comment: @CustomizedName You dont have to call the database, just put the result of `GetSomeChickens()` in some variable and query that.

Comment: @Magnus I am using foreach now and in value using "$" to add url and id then splitting it

Answer (score 0):

The DropDownList doesn't hold the entire object during the binding, only the Text and Value as defined by DataTextField and DataValueField.

In order to get a selected object back, you can have a method to get the ChickenType by passing the ChickenName using Linq like this.

```
List<Chicken> Chickens = GetSomeChickens();
Var Chicken= Chickens.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ChickenName== ddlListMine.SelectedItem.Text);
if(Chicken!= null)
{
  string ChickenType = Chicken.ChickenType ;
}
```